# Juice problem mixtures

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 500 ml container of blackcurrant  made according to the instructions on a bottle of concentrate. The instructions dictate to add 4 parts water to 1 part concentrate. I drink some and now there is only 400 ml in the bottle. I top up the remainder of the container with concentrate. What percentage of the squash in the 500 ml container is now concentrate?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You started with $500mL$ of mixture. Let's work through it together:

1. If we divide the mixture into $5$ parts, we have $1$ part of concentrate and $4$ parts water. How many mililitres of concentrate is in the $500mL$ bottle?
2. Now, answer the same question with $400mL$. If you've drunk a good mixture, the remaining liquid should still have $1$ part concentrate and $4$ parts water.
3. How much concentrate do we add to the bottle to fill it up? Add that to the total amount of concentrate in the bottle.
4. Compute the percentage of concentrate. That is, divide the amount of concentrate in the bottle by the total amount of liquid in the bottle (i.e. water + concentrate), then multiply by $100$. The resulting number is the percentage of concentrate in the bottle.

Comment: Are you sure: The remaining liquid should still have 1 part concentrate and 4 parts water? The answer says it is 36% I thought the answer was 40% too.

Comment: Well, if the liquid is mixed well, then yes, drinking some of the liquid should keep the two ingredients in the same proportion. The proportion will change when we add more concentrate, but drinking some of the mixture (assuming it is well-mixed) will not change the proportion.

Comment: Is it possible for you to solve the question?